# Querying Current Vertex Attribute State in webGL

Tags: webgl

For some reasons (emulating VAOs when they are not available), I'd like to get the current state of the bound vertex attribute arrays, and I obtain results that I do not understand concerning

```
   VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE and VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_TYPE.
```

I tried the following program:

```
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<script src='/webgl-debug.js'></script>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  gl = WebGLDebugUtils.makeDebugContext(gl); // Remove this in production code

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

  var data = [
   -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
   -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
   -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
   -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
    1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0
   ];

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, data, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 1, gl.BYTE, true, 0, 0);

  console.log(gl.getVertexAttrib(0,gl.VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE));
  console.log(gl.getVertexAttrib(0,gl.VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_TYPE) == gl.FLOAT);

</script>
```

I expected to get:

```
1 
false
```

and what I actually get (on Firefox 45.1.1) is:

```
4
true
```

(corresponds to the default values, not the the ones I specified in vertexAttribPointer())

Is there something I did wrong in there ?

**Update (found a workaround)**

I observed that if the corresponding vertex attrib array is enabled, then the queries work as expected:

```
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);    
  console.log(gl.getVertexAttrib(0,gl.VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE));
  console.log(gl.getVertexAttrib(0,gl.VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_TYPE) == gl.BYTE);
```

then I get:

```
1
true
```

Comment: It's a bug in firefox :(   I submitted a conformance test PR [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/pull/1707). If you want to emulate VAOs you should consider tracking state yourself. There's a VAO emulator [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/demos/google/resources/OESVertexArrayObject.js).

Comment: [Filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1275234)